# Presentationally finite group "extensions"

Tags: gr.group-theory, terminology, universal-algebra, combinatorial-group-theory

Fix a group $G$ and fix a presentation of $G$ as $\langle X\mid R\rangle$. A *presentationally finite* extension of $G$ is any group that can be presented as $H=\langle X\cup X'\mid R\cup R'\rangle$, where $X',R'$ are finite. (Mind, the natural homomorphism $G\to H$ may not be injective. If necessary, we can restrict ourselves to cases where it is.)

For example, the presentationally finite extensions of the trivial group are the finitely presentable groups.

> **Question**: Is there an existing name for this kind of group homomorphism/extension?

Unless I've missed something, it's not very hard to see that this does not depend on the choice of presentation of $G$ (sketch: adding extraneous generators to $X$ and the corresponding generation relations to $R$ does not change the isomorphism type (over $G$) of $\langle X\cup X'\mid R\cup R'\rangle$, neither does adding any relations that follow from the existing ones; thus, we can just add all elements of $G$ plus any number of their copies we want, and all relations true in $G$ about them and then remove any redundant ones we do not want to obtain all possible presentations).

Thus, this is really a property of the map $G\to H$ (or the extension $G\leq H$ if the map is injective) and not of a particular presentation.

I'm mostly interested in the case of finitely generated groups, but I think the idea works just as well for arbitrary groups, of arbitrary cardinality.

(Another way to describe this is simply as the groups of the form $H=(G*F)/N$, where $F$ is a free group of finite rank and $N$ is finitely generated as a normal subgroup of $G*F$, such that $N\cap G$ is trivial if we demand that the map $G\to H$ actually be injective.)

Comment: If you only add a single relation, this is called a “relative one-relator group”, which has some literature, eg [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510582.pdf).

Comment: In analogy with the usage in algebraic geometry and commutative algebra, you could say that a morphism of groups $G\to H$ is "of finite presentation" if $H$ arises from $G$ by adding finitely many generators and relations, and call $H$ "finitely presented over $G$"

Comment: @AchimKrause: Oh, that's perfect. Thanks. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. (Well, if there is some other terminology specific to groups, I will accept *that*, but I'm perfectly happy with this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kind of presentation you are  giving is called a relative presentation and has been studied extensively by Steve Pride and his coauthors. So relatively finitely presented over $G$ is probably the best name (I didn't search his papers to see if he uses this term.)

Comment: Indeed, he does use this term. See e.g. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500005290

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any widely used term for this in the context of groups, but in analogy with the usage in algebraic geometry and commutative algebra, you could say that a morphism of groups $G\to H$ is "of finite presentation" if $H$ arises from $G$ by adding finitely many generators and relations, and call $H$ "finitely presented over $G$"

Comment: I agree: I think that "finitely presented over $G$" is the right terminology (in general in universal algebra, hence for groups as well).